# Select Unique Row With Priority Value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have dataset named user_status like the following:

| User | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Done |
| Bob | Done |
| Fred | Waiting |
| Bob | Waiting |
| Bill | Waiting |
| Joe | Done |

What I would like to do is to select everyone in the dataset once, taking the row with Status value "Done" as priority, so the result would be like below:

| User | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Done |
| Bob | Done |
| Fred | Waiting |
| Bill | Waiting |
| Joe | Done |

I've tried case, group by, and few other that didn't work. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`, `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only values, then you can use the alphabetical ordering of status and use `min()`:

```
select user, min(status)
from t
group by user;
```

A more general method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by case when status = 'Done' then 1 else 2 end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `case` gives you flexibility on the ordering.  Plus you can return other columns.